# jQuery toggle expand divs inside bootstrap container wrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]Guys basically there will be a bootstrap container `div`, and inside there will be 4 card style `div`s with toggle expand/retract button. When you click on one card's button, the div will expand all the way to the container's width. Please check the image. I'm a newbie to jQuery and with the script I've, i'm not able to achieve the full width. If someone can help me out it'll be great. Here's the code below -

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#toggle-button').click(function() {
    var toggleWidth = $("#exp_card_1").width() == 600 ? "200px" : "600px";
    $('#exp_card_1').animate({
      width: toggleWidth
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#exp_card_1 {
  position: relative;
  height: 310px;
  background: #2d3644;
  z-index: 1;
}
#toggle-button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 43.7%;
  height: 38px;
  width: 38px;
  background: #131f34 url("../images/arrow.png") no-repeat;
  background-position: 5px 9px;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="padding:0; position:relative;">
  <!-- /.row -->
  <div class="row mar-t25">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
      <div id="exp_card_1">
        <div id="toggle-button"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
      <div class="stock-card curves2">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
      <div id="exp_card_3" class="stock-card curves2">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
      <div id="exp_card_4" class="stock-card curves2">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.row -->
</div>
```

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/7vmckqzk/), are you sure the width really is `600`

Comment: @adeneo - i just gave 600 just to check the toggle width is working. I want the div to expand all the way till the container.

Comment: @adeneo - Please check the attached image.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

I suggest taking a look at MDN to get deeper insights about CSS props: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#toggle-button').click(function() {
    var toggleWidth = $("#exp_card_1").width() > 0 ? "0%" : "100%";
    $('#exp_card_1').animate({
      width: toggleWidth
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#exp_card_1 {
  position: relative;
  height: 310px;
  background: #2d3644;
  z-index: 1;
}
#toggle-button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 43.7%;
  height: 38px;
  width: 38px;
  background: #131f34 url("../images/arrow.png") no-repeat;
  background-position: 5px 9px;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="padding:0; position:relative;">
  <!-- /.row -->
  <div class="row mar-t25">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
      <div id="exp_card_1">
        <div id="toggle-button"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
      <div class="stock-card curves2">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
      <div id="exp_card_3" class="stock-card curves2">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
      <div id="exp_card_4" class="stock-card curves2">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.row -->
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Brewer Gorge i want the div to expand all the way till the container.

Comment: If you're talking about the margin on the corners, you can just set the margin of body to 0 to remove that. Generally I would recommend getting used to the Chrome DevTools (or the FF web inspector) for those kind of styling problems. They really give you instant feedback which is quite useful for beginners.

Comment: Please check the attached image.